# How to send form data in a http post request of angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to send form data of the updated user details to the back end which node server in angular 2,However I couldn't send the form data and the server responds with status of 500,In angularjs  I have done something like this,
**service file**

```
  update: {
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
      dest1: 'update'
    },
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': undefined
    }
  }
```

**In controller as**

```
var fd = new FormData();
var user = {
  _id: StorageFactory.getUserDetail()._id,
  loc: locDetails
};
fd.append('user', angular.toJson(user));
UserService.update(fd).
$promise.then(
  function(value) {
    console.info(value);
    updateUserDetailsInStorage();
  },
  function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
);
```

I couldn't to figure how to do this in angular 2 as angular.toJson,angular.identity and transformrequest features are not available in angular 2,
so far I have done the following in angular 2,

```
 let fd = new FormData();
 let user = {
   _id: this.appManager.getUserDetail()._id,
   loc: locDetails
 };
 fd.append('user', JSON.stringify(user));
 this.userService.update(fd).subscribe((value) => {
   console.log(value);
   this.updateUserDetailsInStorage();
 }, (err) => {
   console.error(err);
 });
```

**http service file**

```
update(body) {
  console.log('update', body);
  const headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': undefined
  });

  const options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });
  return this.http.post(`${app.DOMAIN}` + 'user/update', body, options)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      res.json();
    }).do(data => {
      console.log('response', data);
    })
}
```

I have read many posts and tried few things but so far it was unsuccessful, could anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Where are you unsuccessful exactly? Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: there is no console errors , the server responds with a status of 500 while it works perfectly when I run the same application which I created in angularjs

Comment: If you are sure the post url is correct, can you also JSON.stringify the body variable that you are sending? And maybe change the 'Content-Type' to 'application/json'

Comment: The request payload changes to  {} when I try either of these or both

Answer (score 24):

You can add headers if your server controller requires it else you can simply post it like this

```
let body = new FormData();
body.append('email', 'emailId');
body.append('password', 'xyz');
this.http.post(url, body);
```

Comment: I am confused, for example how can I send this:       `"&client_secret=" + "abc123" +"&username=" + user +"&password=" + pass;`

Comment: @ValRob see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470575/angular-4-httpclient-query-parameters/45470576

Answer (score 6):

This is a functional solution for build a POST request in Angular2, you don't need an Authorization header.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

var body = "firstname=" + user.firstname + "&lastname=" + user.lastname + "&username=" + user.username + "&email=" + user.email + "&password=" + user.password;

return new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.http.post("http://XXXXXXXXXXX/users/create", body, options).subscribe((data) => {
                if (data.json()) {
                    resolve(data.json());
                } else {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            }
        )
    });
```

Comment: It's actually `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` instead of `'application/X-www-form-urlencoded'`. Lowercase X. I was getting 400 Bad Request until I changed it.

Comment: this approach works for my

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method I've used in angular 4 for uploading files....
 for Ui

```
   <input type="file"id="file"(change)="handleFileInput($event)">
```

and .ts file I've added this ....

```
  handleFileInput(event) {
    let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
    let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
    let files: FileList = target.files;
    this.fileToUpload  = files[0];
    console.log(this.fileToUpload);
  }



 uploadFileToActivity() {
    console.log('Uploading file in process...!' + this.fileToUpload );
    this.fontService.upload(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(
      success => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fileToUpload));
        console.log('Uploading file succefully...!');
        console.log('Uploading file succefully...!' + JSON.stringify(success));
      },
      err => console.log(err),
    );
  }
```

and In services

```
upload(fileToUpload: File) {
    const headers = new Headers({'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'});
    // headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    console.log('before hist the service' + formData);
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.appSettings.baseUrl}/Containers/avatar/upload/`, formData , options).map(
        res => {
          const data = res.json();
          return data;
        }
      ).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This method used for single file uploading to the server directory.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method from my app which works fine.

```
 updateProfileInformation(user: User) {
    this.userSettings.firstName = user.firstName;
    this.userSettings.lastName = user.lastName;
    this.userSettings.dob = user.dob;

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', this.constants.jsonContentType);

    var s = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + s);
    var body = JSON.stringify(this.userSettings);

    return this.http.post(this.constants.userUrl + "UpdateUser", body, { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        var result = response.json();
        return result;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to explain how to POST form data in particular. This looks like a request with a normal stringified JSON body. Where is the form data?

Answer (score 0):

FINAL answer
sending like below working fine .

```
         const input = new FormData();
            input['payload'] = JSON.stringify(param);
             console.log(input);
                  alert(input);
                return this.httpClient.post(this.hostnameService.razor + 'pipelines/' + 
                    workflowId, input).subscribe(value => {
                 console.log('response for Manual Pipeline ' + value);
                 return value;
                   }, err => {
                     console.log(err);
                     });
```