# Angular 4 HttpClient Query Parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, http, lodash, angular-httpclient

I have been looking for a way to pass query parameters into an API call with the new `HttpClientModule`'s `HttpClient` and have yet to find a solution. With the old `Http` module you would write something like this.

```js
getNamespaceLogs(logNamespace) {

    // Setup log namespace query parameter
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('logNamespace', logNamespace);

    this._Http.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, { search: params })
}
```

This would result in an API call to the following URL:

`localhost:3001/api/v1/data/logs?logNamespace=somelogsnamespace`

However, the new `HttpClient` `get()` method doesn't have a `search` property, so I am wondering where to pass in the query parameters?

Comment: With Angular 7, you can write your params as an object and use it like this:
`this.httpClient.get(url, { params }`  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211610/5042169

Answer (score 310, accepted):

I ended up finding it through the IntelliSense on the `get()` function. So, I'll post it here for anyone who is looking for similar information.

Anyways, the syntax is nearly identical, but slightly different. Instead of using `URLSearchParams()` the parameters need to be initialized as `HttpParams()` and the property within the `get()` function is now called `params` instead of `search`.

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

```js
getLogs(logNamespace): Observable<any> {

    // Setup log namespace query parameter
    let params = new HttpParams().set('logNamespace', logNamespace);

    return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, { params: params })
}
```

I actually prefer this syntax as its a little more parameter agnostic. I also refactored the code to make it slightly more abbreviated.

```js
getLogs(logNamespace): Observable<any> {

    return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, {
        params: new HttpParams().set('logNamespace', logNamespace)
    })
}
```

**Multiple Parameters**

The best way I have found thus far is to define a `Params` object with all of the parameters I want to define defined within. As @estus pointed out in the comment below, there are a lot of great answers in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3/45459672#45459672) as to how to assign multiple parameters.

```js
getLogs(parameters) {

    // Initialize Params Object
    let params = new HttpParams();

    // Begin assigning parameters
    params = params.append('firstParameter', parameters.valueOne);
    params = params.append('secondParameter', parameters.valueTwo);

    // Make the API call using the new parameters.
    return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, { params: params })
```

**Multiple Parameters with Conditional Logic**

Another thing I often do with multiple parameters is allow the use of multiple parameters without requiring their presence in every call. Using Lodash, it's pretty simple to conditionally add/remove parameters from calls to the API. The exact functions used in Lodash or Underscores, or vanilla JS may vary depending on your application, but I have found that checking for property definition works pretty well. The function below will only pass parameters that have corresponding properties within the parameters variable passed into the function.

```js
getLogs(parameters) {

    // Initialize Params Object
    let params = new HttpParams();

    // Begin assigning parameters
    if (!_.isUndefined(parameters)) {
        params = _.isUndefined(parameters.valueOne) ? params : params.append('firstParameter', parameters.valueOne);
        params = _.isUndefined(parameters.valueTwo) ? params : params.append('secondParameter', parameters.valueTwo);
    }

    // Make the API call using the new parameters.
    return this._HttpClient.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, { params: params })
```

Comment: The first snippet is wrong. `let params = new HttpParams(); params.set(...)` won't work as expected. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459532/why-httpparams-doesnt-work-in-multiple-line-in-angular-4-3/45459672#45459672

Comment: @joshrathke Could you please add how to add header and params together?

Comment: @SavadKP you can set them like this 
this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: params});

and read about  new HttpHeaders like HttpParams

Comment: I guess `new HttpParams({fromObject: { param1: 'value1', ... }});` is the easiest approach (angular 5+) then `params.set(...)`.

Answer (score 98):

You can (in version 5+) use the **fromObject** and **fromString** constructor parameters when creating HttpParamaters to make things a bit easier

```
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2',
      }
    });

    // http://localhost:3000/test?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

or:

```
    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromString: `param1=${var1}&param2=${var2}`
    });

    //http://localhost:3000/test?paramvalue1=1&param2=value2
```

Comment: This is not needed anymore. You can just pass directly a JSON object to HttpClient. `const params = {'key': 'value'}` to:  `http.get('/get/url', { params: params })`

Comment: @danger89 True. But be warned: only string or string[] values allowed!

Comment: Saved huge amount of my time. I was constructing url by appending query params as string to the request url.

Answer (score 31):

You can pass it like this

```
let param: any = {'userId': 2};
this.http.get(`${ApiUrl}`, {params: param})
```

Comment: True but that throws typing out the window

Comment: @DanLatimer You don't have to use any, so you can keep using typing all the way until you pass it to `params`

Comment: @DanLatimer: While generally true, typing is out of the window as soon as you use `HttpParams`, which has no checks whatsoever on whether the params map contains any particular key with a value of any particular type.

Answer (score 12):

A more concise solution:

```
this._Http.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, { 
    params: {
      logNamespace: logNamespace
    } 
 })
```

Answer (score 8):

With Angular 7, 
I got it working by using the following without using HttpParams.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ApiClass {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    // use it like this in other services / components etc.
    this.getDataFromServer().
      then(res => {
        console.log('res: ', res);
      });
  }

  getDataFromServer() {
    const params = {
      param1: value1,
      param2: value2
    }
    const url = 'https://api.example.com/list'

    // { params: params } is the same as { params } 
    // look for es6 object literal to read more
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { params }).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

joshrathke is right.

In angular.io [docs](https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams) is written that **URLSearchParams from @angular/http is deprecated**. Instead you should use **HttpParams from @angular/common/http**. The code is quite similiar and identical to what joshrathke have written.
For multiple parameters that are saved for instance in a object like

```
{
  firstParam: value1,
  secondParam, value2
}
```

you could also do

```
for(let property in objectStoresParams) {
  if(objectStoresParams.hasOwnProperty(property) {
    params = params.append(property, objectStoresParams[property]);
  }
}
```

If you need inherited properties then remove the hasOwnProperty accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an object that can be converted to `{key: 'stringValue'}` pairs, you can use this shortcut to convert it:

```
this._Http.get(myUrlString, {params: {...myParamsObject}});
```

I just love the spread syntax!

Answer (score 2):

**search** property of type **URLSearchParams** in **RequestOptions** class is deprecated in angular 4. Instead, you should use **params** property of type **URLSearchParams**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set JSON object to params.

```
let params = {
logNamespace: 'somelogsnamespace'
//, add more if needed      
};
this._Http.get(`${API_URL}/api/v1/data/logs`, { params: params });
```