# how pass a string with decimal like 18.5 in the URL in Angular

Tags: angular

User selects a string with decimal in it like 17.5,12.5 etc from radio buttons and It will be passed to the Service.ts (in Angular) where API will be called and this value is passed in the URL as a resource.THis is my code in Service.ts.

```
  getRequestedData(  ID: number,  sizeApplicable: string ): Observable<POM[]> {
        debugger;
        let size; 
        if(sizeApplicable.indexOf('.')!=-1){
        size= sizeApplicable.replace( '.', '____' );} 
        console.log(size);
      return this._http.get( this.API_BaseUrl + '/<URL>/'  + ID + '/' + size )
            .map(( response: Response ) => <POM[]>response.json() )
            .catch( this.handleError );
    }
```

As you can see, the decimal is not getting replaced with '____' rather is simply passed with the decimal and as usual it is not considered and it is treated as 18 by Back End application.

Can someone please help to correct this code or suggest a better code in Angular4 to pass this string with decimal in URL.:(
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh8HU.png

Comment: Hello, can you use POST instead of GET ? This way you could simply add the real value in the body of the request.

Comment: Nope. unfortunately, we cannot change this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `encodeURIComponent()`. [See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```js
getRequestedData(ID: number, sizeApplicable: string): Observable<POM[]> {
    if (sizeApplicable.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
        do {
            sizeApplicable = sizeApplicable.replace(/\./g, encodeURIComponent('.'));
        } while (sizeApplicable.indexOf('.') !== -1)
    } 

    return this._http.get(`${this.API_BaseUrl}/<URL>/${ID}/${sizeApplicable}`)
        .map(( response: Response ) => <POM[]>response.json() )
        .catch( this.handleError );
}
```

Comment: Could you please put the code up for me and how will it supposed to encode in the API.

Comment: If you still want to replace `.` with `____` use `'____'` instead of `encodeURIComponent('.')`

But the recommended way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470575/angular-4-httpclient-query-parameters)