# Error on submit form with data in angular

Tags: angular

I tired to submit form data but getting json decode error from laravel api. I don't have access of laravel api side. When i am trying to submit it from swagger it works fine.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://example.com/create-reference' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 883|DuNTAVq5Yl2FbeNEpWMk64dpiF0z8Nem1QG0fHUo54545' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@dart-overview-slide.pdf;type=application/pdf' \
  -F 'reference={
  "contact_person": "Dalia Kadoch",
  "email": "artsandletters@earthlink.net",
  "phone_number": "7821503357",
  "address": "Heriot House, Heriot Road, Chertsey, KT16 0DT",
  "company_name": "The Big Word",
  
}'
```

When i tried to submit it from angular my form body look like this and getting error.

```
    {
     "file" : "tes",
     "reference" : {
  "id": 1,
  "contact_person": "Dalia Kadoch",
  "email": "artsandletters@earthlink.net",
  "phone_number": "7821503357",
  "address": "Heriot House, Heriot Road, Chertsey, KT16 0DT",
  "company_name": "The Big Word",
  "document_url": "https://image.com/image.jpeg"
} }
```

But I am getting json.decode() error from laravel.

json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The swagger/curl request is submitting [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) with two fields named `file` and `reference`.

From the [curl manual](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html):

> -F/--form <name=content>
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the content-type multipart/form-data according to RFC1867. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the letter <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.

In your Angular approach, it looks like you are submitting a JSON object with the `file` and `reference` fields, but a JSON object is not `FormData`.

You can learn how to submit `FormData` in the following Stack Overflow post: [How to send form data in a http post request of angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41031890/how-to-send-form-data-in-a-http-post-request-of-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks @Sam Herrmann you for helping me and not to mark this question as a duplicate. Most of people just mark ki duplicate.